# How to split video file by ffmpeg?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have this code to split video to multiple parts:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.mp4) do ( 
  ffmpeg -i "%%~i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:05 "D:\Ebook\%%~ni_1.mp4"
  ffmpeg -i "%%~i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:10 "D:\Ebook\%%~ni_2.mp4"
  ffmpeg -i "%%~i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:10 "D:\Ebook\%%~ni_3.mp4"
  )
pause
```

However, it only can split mp4 file. Now I have more type file such as:mkv and avi. How to split all with exactly output. Thanks !

Comment: It works the same way for all input types. Have you tried with mkv and avi?

Comment: Yes, Of course it works but I want to ask about type file. Example: how to split avi file to 3 avi files, not mp4 file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried something like:

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.avi) do ( 
  ffmpeg -i "%%~i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:05 "D:\Ebook\%%~ni_1.avi"
  ffmpeg -i "%%~i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:05 -t 00:00:10 "D:\Ebook\%%~ni_2.avi"
  ffmpeg -i "%%~i" -vcodec copy -acodec copy -ss 00:00:10 "D:\Ebook\%%~ni_3.avi"
  )
pause
```

Note that I'm not familiar with the Windows globbing in batch files- I'm assuming %%~i is correct form.

Comment: Oh, yes it works and I created 3x time